Expo react native firebase access token expires
After searching the web, I found that the Firebase auth tokens automatically refresh every hour. That's a function of the SDK, and you don't have to do anything to enable it, but it seems that my SDK inside my react native expo app doesn't work like that. I have doubts that it's because I'm using ReactNativeAsyncStorage as a persistent unit in my app. So I'm writing this question to figure out what's the best way to refresh my access token in my case? Is the best way to check if it has expired in my react toolkit query?
Here is my firebase config
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {
    getAuth,
    initializeAuth,
    getReactNativePersistence,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
};


export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage),
});

export const auth = getAuth(app);


"it seems that my SDK inside my react native expo app doesn't work like that" - what exactly did you observe that leads you to this conclusion?  Please edit the question to share these debugging details, and all relevant code that someone can use to reproduce the issue.

@DougStevenson Sorry about that, it's because the access token expires after an hour and it doesn't get auto renewed and I assumed it's because of that

Your code matters in this case.  We can't tell if your code is correctly responding to the refresh.  It's a common error, and we need to see if you're making that mistake.  Please read about how to create a minimal reproducible example so that we can copy what you have and observe the same issue.  Without that, we can't be of much help.

Thank you for that, but I don't understand what code you would want to see? The redux query?

You need to show the code that you used to observe the problem.  How exactly do you know the token doesn't refresh?  What lines of code are telling you that, and what can we do to reproduce the issue?  Please edit the question to show your debugging details,.
